# Carbonite/Mozy comparison?

Tags: backup, windows-backup

Has anyone done a Carbonite/Mozy comparison?

Answer (score 5):

Don't forget [Backblaze](http://www.backblaze.com/).

Comment: Or [SpiderOak](https://spideroak.com/) if you need Linux support.

Answer (score 2):

[Yes](http://www.restorationfinder.com/carbonite-mozy-service-holds-edge-online-backup) I believe [there](http://bestonlinestorage.com/carbonite-vs-mozy-home-a-review-and-comparison/) are [a](http://www.goodwebpractices.com/other/unlimited-online-backup-mozy-carbonite.html) few [floating](http://www.techwizbackup.com/carbonite-vs-mozy) around [on](http://www.goodwebpractices.com/other/unlimited-online-backup-mozy-carbonite.html) the [interweb](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qpKCezk3HnU).

I have installed Mozy (free) on my wife's computer and it has been running without any issues for a couple of years now.

Answer (score 2):

I've been running MozyHome for a couple years and found it to be a solid product.
In the rare instances I've needed restores, it worked flawlessly, though I never had to restore a large amount. I did find it to be a *severe* memory hog if you enable the option to decorate icons in Explorer with green checkmarks to indicate a file is backed up or not. My Explorer and Mozy backup applications where each running several hundred MB in virtual memory size and very noticeably and very negatively affecting system performance. If you disable this feature, it uses much less memory (I have about 130GB backed up - smaller backup sets may not have this memory problem.)

Recently (Q12011), Mozy changed their pricing structure and the cost for my 130GB was going to jump from $56 to $250/year, so now I am starting to try Carbonite. Some of the online reviews mentioned above do not point this out.

So far is it going well. Carbonite is in the middle of the initial backup and I've not selected everything yet, but it does what I find to be a better job of choosing "defaults" of what to backup and what to omit. I expect it to take another week or two to finish uploading. It seems to recognize most temp directories and exclude them, etc. The UI is more responsive for selecting what to backup/exclude. I've not gotten to the point of having to restore yet.

Carbonite does not appear to have an option to also backup/mirror to a separate hard drive (i.e. I used this with Mozy to back up to an external attached drive as well as via the cloud). Nor will Carbonite backup data on an external drive - only internal drives.

I don't think there is an option to use regular expressions or other patterns
to include/exclude files/dirs. For example, I'd like to exclude 
C:\Users*\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\History*
because Chrome creates large "History Archive yyyy-mm" files over time
but puts them in a directory with other profile files that I'd like to backup.